# When cancer is detectable, how many sub-clones are there at that stage?

Tags: cancer, theoretical-biology, mutations

I have read somewhere that cancer is detectable when the number of cells reaches $10^7 - 10^9$, which probably varies according to the specific tumor. At this early stage, what is the expected number of subclones of the tumor? Any references would be super appreciated!

p/s: To answer this, I tried running a simple code for a birth-death process, but my laptop freezes at $10^7$ cells. :(

Comment: Is this in humans? What is the form of detection? There are over 100 different types of cancer, so maybe pick one?

Comment: @Andrew Any example in human cancer would be sufficient. Thank you for pointing out the confusion!

Comment: How do you define *subclones*?

Comment: It is impossible to define subclones. But is is possible to define when metastasis. Thus, this question may be unanswerable.

Comment: @MattDMo I apologize. I was under the impression that this is a well-defined concept. I have seen some phylogenetic trees for keeping track of cancer mutation, which is why I assume they are what biologists consider subclones.